# Invisibility of EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Why my EditText is not visible?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem? May be a image or your xml code?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not clear from the question, but assuming you drag and drop an EditText onto the Design page, but it is not showing.

If that is the case,
Try dragging and droping the EditText into "Component Tree", which can be found below the "Palette"

or

Switch to "Text" tab instead of drag and drop, and Type in

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then Switch back to Design tab.